# Repairing cryfs

Tags: 18.04, cryfs

I am using the plasma-vault. Some of my files are corrupted:

```
./.ssh_20180502/known_hosts.BNHi4klH9P
find: ‘./.ssh_20180502/config’: Input/output error
```

File system is fine. `fsck` has been run on the partition and no errors were reported. It is Kubuntu.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/qCT8ygmT) are the `smartctl` results.

How can we repair these files ?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu/Kubuntu are you using?

Comment: "Input/Output Error" often indicates a hardware problem, with corrupted files merely another symptom. Look up how to run a SMART test on your storage device to rule out that cause.

Comment: Its Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Filesystem is fine. fsck has been run on the partition and no errors were reported. It is Kubuntu

Comment: rsiwal@rsiwal-in:/opt/forticlientsslvpn$ ls -l /mnt/encrypted/ |grep -v rsiwal
ls: cannot access '/mnt/encrypted/test.tgz': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/mnt/encrypted/test.kdbx': Input/output error
total 348
-????????? ? ?      ?           ?            ? test.kdbx
-????????? ? ?      ?           ?            ? test.tgz

Comment: Please do not bury important information in comments (which many don't read) - edit your original question instead. `fsck` is not a SMART test.

Comment: Here are the smartctl results:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qCT8ygmT